# Bluetooth Audio Lag and Out of syc

Tags: sound, 15.04, pulseaudio, bluetooth

Am using Ubuntu 15.04 , i have a bluetooth speaker Blurock2 .
it was working fine until recently. there is Lag and sometime audio is out of sync with video. Especial after pressing Pause or Skipping video.

please help. 
a step by step guide will be nice
if any details are needed please tell me and i will post.
running on Acer 5750

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using a bluetooth dongle, and it worked fine (Ubuntu 15.10). Then it started giving me audio lags and sync problems.

It occurred to me that I had also begun to use a new usb drive in the port just next to the bluetooth dongle. When I moved the dongle to the other side of my laptop, the lag stopped.

I can't be certain if it was the USB drive that caused the interruptions, but changing the ports did the trick. I couldn't find any other solutions in my research.